# Kotlin Gradle plugin version mismatch

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using kotlin 1.7.20. But one plugin using Kotlin 1.3.50. it giving issue. How can we bypass this issue?

[image]

Comment: check this : https://github.com/Afur/flutter_html_to_pdf/issues/72